# How can I turn OFF encryption on a Honeycomb tablet?

Tags: 3.0-honeycomb, encryption

I used the "Encrypt tablet" option on the "Location & security" page of my settings to fully encrypt my up-to-date Asus Transformer. Honeycomb encryption seems a bit flaky so I want to un-encrypt my tablet again. How can I do this? (the option on the settings page still says "Encrypt tablet" and underneath it says "Encrypted", but tapping it does nothing, and I can't find any way to decrypt the tablet again)

Owen

Answer (score 1):

Did some research on this myself before I turned on encryption on my Iconia... the *only* way to decrypt the tablet is to do a factory data wipe. The UI should have gave you this warning when you chose "Encrypt tablet" (the Iconia sure did). If you back your stuff up, wipe, and restore your backup, you should be fine. (That's where root + Titanium Backup + ClockWorkMod + Nandroid comes in handy)

[This Engadget post](http://www.engadget.com/2011/02/02/android-3-0-honeycomb-can-encrypt-all-your-data-needs-a-full/) shows the UI and it's warning about the inability to decrypt.